# how to use pipeline in linux?

Tags: linux

I have a software working in linux, like *test_sf*

```
test_sf --input test.fastq --output test.results
```

It will output a file named *test.results*

but I have *test1.fastq.gz*, *test2.fastq.gz*, how can use these two files instead of unzip it?

```
zcat test1.fastq.gz | test_st --input --output test1.results
zcat test1.fastq.gz | test_st --input --output test1.results
```

These two commands did not work.

**Note:This is just a toy command to show my question.**

Comment: 1) read yourself and correct your example, 2) have a look at `xargs` 3) there's no need to tag with [R] here.

Comment: What does `test_st` do? Does it read from standard input? That is all the pipe does, take standard output from the left and runs it to standard input on the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this command:

```
test_sf --input test.fastq --output test.results
```

You would ideally run this, but you can't because your program doesn't support compressed input:

```
test_sf --input test.fastq.gz --output test.results # probably fails
```

So you need to use `zcat` to unzip the file, and pipe it in.  Some programs understand `-` to be a magic filename meaning stdin, in which case you can do this:

```
zcat test.fastq | test_sf --input - --output test.results # might work
```

If your program also does not understand `-` as special, you can use this in Bash:

```
test_sf --input <(zcat test.fastq.gz) --output test.results # should work
```

What this does is invoke your program with a command line actually like this:

```
test_sf --input /dev/XXX --output test.results
```

Where XXX is some special filename which actually is a pipe where zcat will write.  This way, so long as your program supports reading serially from a file (not requiring random access to the input), it will almost certainly work.  This last technique is described further here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101143/how-can-i-stream-data-to-a-program-that-expects-to-read-data-from-a-file-that-is

Comment: Thanks. I tested the first two and it worked, but haven't tried the third.